# Proxy Issue with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6, php-8.2

I'm working on a Symfony project and I've encountered a problem when trying to ping or make a Curl request from the terminal to my Symfony site (Symfony 6 and PHP 8.2).
I use [Symfony Local Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com)

My Symfony site uses the domain name [SITE_NAME.local] and works correctly when accessed through the browser.
However, when I attempt to ping from the terminal using the command ping [SITE_NAME.local], I get the following error: "ping: cannot resolve [SITE_NAME.local]: Unknown host."
Additionally, when I try to make a Curl request from the terminal using the command curl [SITE_NAME.local], I also encounter an error.

I've already tried to update the /etc/hosts file, but it resulted in me losing access to the site via the browser (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

```
127.0.0.1 SITE_NAME.local
```

[image]
Despite these issues, my Symfony site works fine when accessed through the browser. My goal is to be able to make Curl requests from the terminal to my local project. Do you have any suggestions on what might be causing this problem and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What entry did you try in `\etc\hosts` that caused a problem with the browser?

Comment: I tried with 127.0.0.1 SITE_NAME.local

Comment: How does "losing access" look like? Is this a problem directly related to PHP 8.2 or Symfony 6?

Comment: I have this ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I've added a screenshot to my question

Comment: Firewall rules related to icmp !?!?